# Is it possible to downgrade a CPU from an i7 to a Pentium in a Samsung RF511 laptop?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I have a [2011 Samsung RF511](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/np-rf511) laptop with a core that's been baked a bit too much. I want to replace it with a cheap, lower power CPU so that I can still use the PC as a home security hub and other constant, low-demand tasks without it overheating on idle or crashing.

I know that motherboards on laptops usually need replacement when upgrading to a faster CPU, but do I need to worry about compatibility when downgrading?

The CPU would also draw 10 watts less, so power supply should not be an issue.

Essentially, going from an i7-2630QM to a Pentium b940 or similar CPU.

The GPU is soldered on, but the CPU is actually swappable:

[image: motherboard]

The CPU is on the right in this picture.

There is a black plastic rectangle with a circle in it which can be turned to reduce or increase tension on the CPU. It actually pushes the CPU to the side to secure it, and then the heat tubes screw in on top to push it down.

Comment: Are you sure the CPU can be replaced? It isn't in most laptops.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia That laptop uses a Socket G2 (rPGA988B) so it’s *possible* that it *might* work from a physical hardware perspective. But past that? If the motherboard doesn’t support a downgrade to a non i5 or i7 CPU that’s that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The answer is downgrading the CPU on a Samsung RF511 is a definite maybe. You are better off just using it as-is but with tuned down settings (if possible) for your needs.

That laptop has a [Socket G2 (rPGA988B)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G2) socket on it and [as explained on this site](http://www.cpu-world.com/Sockets/Socket%20G2%20%28rPGA988B%29.html):

> Although all microprocessors from the table below physically fit into the socket, not all of them may be supported by your motherboard. For that reason before upgrading to any model from this list below, **please make sure that the CPU is compatible with the motherboard**.

So the answer is a big… Maybe!

The [Intel Mobile Pentium B940](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium_Dual-Core/Intel-Pentium%20Mobile%20B940.html) model CPU is mentioned in the grid on that article. So if you are willing to gamble, go for it. But honestly it almost seems as if you should just see if you can tweak the settings on that laptop to make it operate at a lower speed overall and just use that as your home security hub.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured.  I ordered a new CPU (since I found once for 6$ on ebay) and will give it a shot for the heck of it.  I'll update this once I get it and try it (in two weeks).